# QT QMediaPlayer is not found, despite the addition of multimedia in the make file

Tags: c++, qt

HI I recently Downloaded the latest version of the QT IDE for Windows 7, despite including multimedia to the make file it still cannot find any of the QMedia libraries, I wanted to know if anyone else had similar problems, and if there is anyone who knows how to solve this.

Comment: It is QMediaPlayer, not QMultimediaPlayer

Comment: I meant to say that, my appologies

Comment: Are you using QtCreator? Did you add `QT += multimedia` to your .pro file? Also, did you run qmake after adding it?

Comment: That was the problem, I hadnt run qmake, thank you for your help Lahiru

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If yours is a qmake-based project, as default projects are in Qt Creator, you have to add following line to your `.pro` file to use the multimedia library:

```
QT += multimedia
```

After making a change to the `.pro` file, you always need to run `qmake` to update the actual `Makefile` which is used for building the app.

You can run it from Qt Creator by right-clicking on the topmost project node in the project explorer, and selecting "Run qmake".

Answer (score 0):

Put ,

```
QT += multimedia
```

Inside your **.pro** file

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30482552)

Comment: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: multimedia